# I'm trying to list(ls) a folder by ssh-ing into a server. Is there any command to store the output as array?

Tags: shell, ssh, find, ls

I'm tried using this command

```
array=`find ssh userName@Host ls Root/top/directory -type d`
```

but it's stored only as a single variable instead of array.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the `MYARRAY=(elem1 elem2 elem3)` notation for creating an array in bash.

So it will be:

```
array=($(ssh userName@Host find Root/top/directory -type d))
```

Answer (score 1):

Split it up with awk or cut and then iterate over your array variable with an integer. Since ls prints on new lines, you can just loop.

```
array=find ssh userName@Host ls Root/top/directory -type d
i=0
echo array | while read LINE;
do
myarray=${LINE[$i]}
i=$((i+1))
done
```

Comment: Hi malfy, Im not an expert user in shell. can you please explain it?

Answer (score 0):

[Creating array from listing of files in directory](http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/140058-simple-list-file-ls-array.html)